# Azure Pipeline Build Error in Web forms project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I had my pipeline working fine for a while, but last week it started to show this error:

```
##[error]WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln(0,0): Error MSB4014: The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectInSolution.get_AbsolutePath()
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.AddPropertyGroupForSolutionConfiguration(ProjectRootElement msbuildProject, SolutionFile solutionFile, SolutionConfigurationInSolution solutionConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateTraversalInstance(String wrapperProjectToolsVersion, Boolean explicitToolsVersionSpecified, List`1 projectsInOrder)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateSolutionProject(String wrapperProjectToolsVersion, Boolean explicitToolsVersionSpecified)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.Generate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.GenerateSolutionWrapper(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, IReadOnlyCollection`1 targetNames, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.LoadSolutionForBuild(String projectFile, PropertyDictionary`1 globalPropertiesInstances, String toolsVersion, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded, IReadOnlyCollection`1 targetNames, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.LoadSolutionIntoConfiguration(BuildRequestConfiguration config, BuildRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueBuildSubmissionToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild)
     0>D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014: The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectInSolution.get_AbsolutePath()
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.AddPropertyGroupForSolutionConfiguration(ProjectRootElement msbuildProject, SolutionFile solutionFile, SolutionConfigurationInSolution solutionConfiguration)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateTraversalInstance(String wrapperProjectToolsVersion, Boolean explicitToolsVersionSpecified, List`1 projectsInOrder)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateSolutionProject(String wrapperProjectToolsVersion, Boolean explicitToolsVersionSpecified)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.Generate()
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.GenerateSolutionWrapper(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, IReadOnlyCollection`1 targetNames, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.LoadSolutionForBuild(String projectFile, PropertyDictionary`1 globalPropertiesInstances, String toolsVersion, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded, IReadOnlyCollection`1 targetNames, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.LoadSolutionIntoConfiguration(BuildRequestConfiguration config, BuildRequest request)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
D:\a\1\s\WebForms\PowerDetails WebForms.sln : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueBuildSubmissionToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild)**
**Build FAILED.**
```

This is an ASP.NET webform website project, and it has been working pretty well for one year, and for some reason start to give us that error.

Also, I have tried to run the pipeline using a branch where it built successfully in the past, and it got the same error.

Anyone is having this error recently?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. I was able to run a successful build after changing the pipeline agent specification from windows-2019 to vs2017-win2016.

Comment: It should be noted that, whilst this is a valid workaround, reducing the VS version may not be compatible with newer features. Please check other answers before resorting to this, such as Simon Opelt's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66687065/1250365

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue tracked here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Starting-today-we-can-no-longer-build-an/1370287, please follow it to get latest feedback.

BTW, you could use [self-hosted agents](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases) with particular version which worked previously in pipeline to continue your work.

**Update**>>The product group has fixed this issue, and the newer version of VS including this fix is released this week and they will take it on images as soon as it is available, see: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2968#issuecomment-803798593 for details.

Comment: Hi, the issue you linked to states that the issue has been mitigated and we are still seeing OPs symptoms. Any updates?

Comment: Pipeline still having the same issue, do you know if they have any new updates?

Comment: I have updated the answer so you could find the latest feedback from the product group.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to a change in the msbuild or build task infrastructure. For some projects the build stopped working a few days back if the solution contained projects of the type "Web Site `{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}`".

Those have not been supported well in the last 5-10 years and there are probably not that many left let alone once built in Azure DevOps which would explain why this regression might have slipped through.

Comment: This was the issue for us. We had one large, legacy Web Site in our solution that we hadn't yet updated to a Web Project. Removing it from our solution allowed us to continue building. We'll either need to update the Web Site to a Web Project or create a separate solution and build pipeline for it going forward.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also being tracked here:

"MSBuild failing with error MSB4041 on windows-2019 image versions 20210309.0 and 20210316.1"
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2968